# Lxml element equality with namespaces

Tags: python, lxml, xml-namespaces

I am attempting to use Lxml to parse the contents of a .docx document.  I understand that lxml replaces namespace prefixes with the actual namespace, however this makes it a real pain to check what kind of element tag I am working with. I would like to be able to do something like

```
if (someElement.tag == "w:p"):
```

but since lxml insists on prepending te ful namespace I'd either have to do something like

```
if (someElemenet.tag == "{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}p'):
```

or perform a lookup of the full namespace name from the element's nsmap attribute like this

```
targetTag = "{%s}p" % someElement.nsmap['w']
if (someElement.tag == targetTag):
```

If there were was an easier way to convince lxml to either

1. Give me the tag string without the namespace appended to it, I can use the prefix attribute along with this information to check which tag I'm working with OR
2. Just give me the tag string using the prefix

This would save a lot of keystrokes when writing this parser.  Is this possible? Am I missing something in the documentation?

Comment: You don't ever want to match on the prefix, as the prefix is completely arbitrary. A valid .docx file could have any prefix, even 'xyz', as long as it was assigned to the same actual namespace string. lxml is doing you a favor by preventing you from relying on the namespace prefix for matching.

Answer (score 22):

Perhaps use [local-name()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name):

```
import lxml.etree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring('<root xmlns:f="foo"><f:test/></root>')
elt=tree[0]
print(elt.xpath('local-name()'))
# test
```

Answer (score 5):

I could not find a way to obtain the non-namespaced tag name from an element -- lxml considers the full namespace part of the tag name. Here are a few options which may help..

You could also use the `QName` class to construct a namespaced tag for comparisons:

```
import lxml.etree
from lxml.etree import QName

tree = lxml.etree.fromstring('<root xmlns:f="foo"><f:test/></root>')
qn = QName(tree.nsmap['f'], 'test')
assert tree[0].tag == qn
```

If you need the bare tag name you'll have to write a utility function to extract it:

```
def get_bare_tag(elem):
    return elem.tag.rsplit('}', 1)[-1]

assert get_bare_tag(tree[0]) == 'test'
```

Unfortunately, to my knowledge you can't search for tags with "any namespace" (e.g. `{*}test`) using lxml's xpath / find methods.

**Updated**: Note that lxml won't construct a tag that contains only `{ or }` -- it will raise ValueError: invalid tag name, so it is safe to assume that an element whose tag name starts with `{` is balanced.

```
lxml.etree.Element('{foo')
ValueError: Invalid tag name
```

Comment: A bit wasteful, especially the `[1:]`. To get the "bare tag", all you need is `elem.tag.split('}')[-1]`. Note that neither this code nor yours cares about unbalanced braces.

Comment: Used `rsplit` to be more efficient, assuming the namespace urls tend to be long.

Comment: Good point. You didn't get rid of the pointless `if` statement; non-namespace tags tend to be short.

Comment: My head is juggling 5 different things at the moment... Simplified it to one line. Thanks John.

Comment: [sigh] I was going to say "... unbalanced braces, which are impossible" but thought that I'd be regarded like Sybil Fawlty as "statin' the bleedin' obvious" :)

Comment: +1 for suggesting the QName class. As for obtaining the local name (if you really have to) you can use xpath: `elem.xpath('local-name()')`

Answer (score 5):

[`etree.Qname`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.QName-class.html) should be able to get you what you want.

```python
from lxml import etree

# [...]

tag = etree.QName(someElement)

print(tag.namespace, tag.localname)
```

For your example tag, this will output:

```
http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main p
```

Note that `QName` will take either the `Element` object or a string (such as from `Element.tag`).

And, as you note, you can also use `Element.nsmap` to map from an arbitrary prefix to a namespace.

So something like this:

```
if tag.namespace == someElement.nsmap["w"] and tag.localname == "p":
```

Answer (score 2):

To save time when looking for high-volume tags like `p` (paragraph, I presume) in docx or `c` (cell) in xlsx, it's usual to set up the full tag once at the global or class level:

```
WPML_URI = "{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}"
tag_p = WPML_URI + 'p'
tag_t = WPML_URI + 't'
```

I have never seen an explanation of why one would want to use `QName()`.

In the other direction, given a full tag, you can extract the base tag easily:

`base_tag = full_tag.rsplit("}", 1)[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Python expert, but I also had this problem (Windows 7 "Contacts" files).  I wrote the following function for the lxml system.

This function takes an element, and returns its tag with the prefix substituted from the file's ns tag.

```
from lxml import etree

def denstag(ee):
  tag = ee.tag
  for ns in ee.nsmap:
    prefix = "{"+ee.nsmap[ns]+"}"
    if tag.startswith(prefix):               
      return ns+":"+tag[len(prefix):]
  return tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for restoring real (source) xml tag name

Assuming we have `xml_node` variable, an instance of lxml `Element`

Before: `{http://some/namespace/url}TagName` (as read from `xml_node.tag` prop)

After: `nsprefix:TagName` (as result of `xml_get_real_tag_name(xml_node)`)

```
def xml_get_real_tag_name(xml_node):
    """Replace lxml '{http://some/namespace/url}TagName' with regular 'nsprefix:TagName' string
    Args:
        xml_node (lxml.etree.Element) Source xml node entity
    Returns:
        str
    """
    if '{' in xml_node.tag:
    return ':'.join([xml_node.prefix, etree.QName(xml_node).localname])
else:
    return xml_node.tag
```